# Remote Build jenkins with curl

Tags: curl, jenkins

I am trying to make a script to build my job remotely using a curl command as followed : ( and  and TOKEN were replaced for security issue)

```
curl -X POST http://<user>:<password>@hudson.mtvi.com/hudson/job/androidplatform_pipeline/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&branch=/master
```

here is the error I get:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

though im certain that master branch exist and that we have a branch parameter

Comment: is that error being returned over the API, or does the build actually start and fail with that error in the console output?

Comment: if your open for other options then you can try jenkins cli. You can find the details under manage jenkins/jenkins cli. and if you want to deal with only Curl ,my suggestion would be to try and build a job which has no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There's inline docs in jenkins on this. If you go to some job that has a "Build Now" button, go to the bottom of the page and click "REST API" (this adds an /api to the end of the job url). At the bottom of the resulting page is a section, "Perform a build", that gives you the actual urls you should use for your job to perform a build, depending on whether or not you need parameters. For builds with parameters, you need to add /buildWithParameters to the end of the job. It looks like you got this far, but just in case the url is slightly different, this is the general answer to the question.

Do each of your branches have job urls? If that's the case, maybe your issue is that you were trying to post to the parent job page with a branch parameter when in fact you can post to the branch itself and omit that parameter (maybe your job actually doesn't require parameters and you can use the normal suffix, "build", instead of "buildWithParameters").